# alias for a dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, alias

```
DECLARE @listStr varchar(MAX);
set @liststr =
        (
  select Units   + ',' + Volume  + ','+ Value   from test_pivot_table where country = 'UK' for xml path('')
        )
DECLARE @query varchar(MAX);
set @query =
        (
        'SELECT ' + @listStr + ' FROM [dbo].[RB_THI_UK_4_4_4_Fact_03012019]'
        )
execute(@query)
```

output of the query is :

```
f001 f002   f003
40  12  60
30  9   53
```

but I need output to be:

```
units volume    value
40  12  60
30  9   53
```

so basically i want to use alias in this dynamic query where actual fields name are f001,f002,f003 and fetching output using mapping table

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I don't understand how your query would be generating that output.  Edit your question and show the value of `@query` after it is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
select Units + ' as [Units], ' + Volume  + ' as [Volume], '+ Value + ' as 'Value]
from test_pivot_table
where country = 'UK' for xml path('');
```

I think your query would only do that if `test_pivot_table` has the values `f001`, `f002`, and `f003` in its columns.  Hence, this should work.

Comment: test_pivot_table- sample :
Units          Volume          Value
F000000000000000000100000000000000000000 F000000000000000000200000000000000000000 F000000000000000000300000000000000000000
R1           R2           R3
other table - sample
F000000000000000000100000000000000000000 F000000000000000000200000000000000000000 F000000000000000000300000000000000000000
40 12 60
30 9 53
i am dynamically selecting table 2 columns using test_pivot_table , so above method is not working

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you've misused column names, so just write your column names into `@query`:

```
set @query =
        (
        'SELECT Units, Volume, Value FROM [dbo].[RB_THI_UK_4_4_4_Fact_03012019]'
        )
```

Comment: . . My apologies.  I undeleted my question and then when I edited it, the edit showed up on your question.  I think that is because your answer appeared as I was doing that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  it is okay:)